# Conditionally align two dataframes in order to derive a column passed in as a condition in numpy where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, array-broadcasting

I come from a SQL background and new to python. I have been trying to figure out how to solve this particular problem for awhile now and am unable to come up with anything.

Here are my dataframes

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

Names1 = {'First_name': ['Jon','Bill','Billing','Maria','Martha','Emma']}
df = DataFrame(Names1,columns=['First_name'])
print(df)

names2 = {'name': ['Jo', 'Bi', 'Ma']}
df_2 = DataFrame(names2,columns=['name'])
print(df_2)
```

Results to this:

```
   First_name
0        Jon
1       Bill
2    Billing
3      Maria
4     Martha
5       Emma
  name
0   Jo
1   Bi
2   Ma
```

This code helps me identify in df which First_name starts with a tuple from df_2

```
df['like_flg'] = np.where(df['First_name'].str.startswith(tuple(list(df_2['name']))), 'true', df['First_name'])
```

results to this:

```
First_name  like_flg
0   Jon     true
1   Bill    true
2   Billing true
3   Maria   true
4   Martha  true
5   Emma    Emma
```

I would like the final output of the dataframe to set the like_flg to the value of the tuple in which the First_name field is being conditionally compared against. See below for final desired output:

```
First_name  like_flg
0   Jon     Jo
1   Bill    Bi
2   Billing Bi
3   Maria   Ma
4   Martha  Ma
5   Emma    Emma
```

Here's what I've tried so far

```
df['like_flg'] = np.where(df['First_name'].str.startswith(tuple(list(df_2['name']))), tuple(list(df_2['name'])), df['First_name'])
```

results to this error:

```
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (3,) (6,)`
```

I've also tried aligning both dataframes, however, that won't work for the use case that I'm trying to achieve.

Is there a way to conditionally align dataframes to fill in the columns that start with the tuple?

I believe the issue I'm facing is that the tuple or dataframe that I'm using as a comparison is not the same size as the dataframe that I want to append the tuple to. Please see above for the desired output.

Thank you all advance!

Comment: is `df_2` always only 2 characters, or can it be more/less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your starting strings differ in length, you can use `.str.extract`

```
df['like_flag'] = df['First_name'].str.extract('^('+'|'.join(df_2.name)+')')
df['like_flag'] = df['like_flag'].fillna(df.First_name)  # Fill non matches.
```

---

I modified `df_2` to be

```
  name
0   Jo
1   Bi
2  Mar
```

which leads to:

```
  First_name like_flag
0        Jon        Jo
1       Bill        Bi
2    Billing        Bi
3      Maria       Mar
4     Martha       Mar
5       Emma      Emma
```

Comment: This nice one :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use np.where,

```
df['like_flg'] = np.where(df.First_name.str[:2].isin(df_2.name), df.First_name.str[:2], df.First_name)

    First_name  like_flg
0   Jon         Jo
1   Bill        Bi
2   Billing     Bi
3   Maria       Ma
4   Martha      Ma
5   Emma        Emma
```

Comment: find an alt :-)

Comment: ah, so this one is basically comparing a substring of the First_name column. I accepted @ALollz answer due to it being more flexible, thank you for the response!

Comment: @noypikobe24 if they are all 2 characters though I think this solution is more appropriate and probably much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Do with `numpy` `find`

```
v=df.First_name.values.astype(str)
s=df_2.name.values.astype(str)

df_2.name.dot((np.char.find(v,s[:,None])==0))
array(['Jo', 'Bi', 'Bi', 'Ma', 'Ma', ''], dtype=object)
```

Then we just assign it back

```
df['New']=df_2.name.dot((np.char.find(v,s[:,None])==0))
df.loc[df['New']=='','New']=df.First_name
df
  First_name   New
0        Jon    Jo
1       Bill    Bi
2    Billing    Bi
3      Maria    Ma
4     Martha    Ma
5       Emma  Emma
```